# Cannot convert const char to string constructing string

Tags: c++

Why does this work

```
auto f = std::string();
f = "src.Id";
```

But this does not

```
std::string f();
f = "src.Id";
```

Comment: Lookup "the most vexing parse" in C++.

Comment: I wish people wouldn't call this simple case *the most vexing parse*. This is the most vexing parse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse.

Comment: Arguably, whichever vexing parse you're experiencing at the moment is the most vexing parse. :)

Comment: If you use the newer syntax `std::string f{};`, it won't consider `f` a declaration of a function returning `std::string`.

Comment: @john: perhaps you should correct Scott Meyers (who invented the term) - see his comment *"Widget w3(); // most vexing parse! declares a function!"* [here](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.jp/2015/09/thoughts-on-vagaries-of-c-initialization.html).  Just because WIkipedia only lists a more complex example doesn't mean the simpler example isn't also covered by the term.

Comment: @TonyDelroy That's interesting but I fail to see how the two cases are related. The more complex case really is much more vexing, it takes much more knowledge to understand what's going on. The OP's case is easy once you've had it explained. Scott Meyers original example was the complex case. Why call two different things with the same name?

Comment: @john: because the fundamental issue is the same... *with or without arguments*, the language assumes a function declaration where it would otherwise be ambiguous and  the programmer may have intended a default-constructed variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because

```
std::string f();
```

declares a function `f` which takes no arguments and returns a string. It's often (but wrongly) called the most vexing parse.

Comment: Tony Delroy is right.